# InvalidArgumentError: logits and labels must have the same first dimension

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, tensorflow-datasets

I am trying to classify images. Those images have different shapes, but this is not a problem.

However, I am trying to create a dataset using the `tf.data.Dataset.from_generator` function provided by **Tensorflow** and I have the feeling that something is not working as it should.

Here is the code:

```py
filenames_ds = tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices(categ_img[:1000]['image_name'])
labels_ds    = tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices(categ_img[:1000]['category_label'])
images_ds    = filenames_ds.map(lambda x: tf.image.decode_jpeg(tf.read_file(x)))
labels_ds    = labels_ds.map(lambda x: tf.one_hot(x, NUM_CATEGORIES))
ds = tf.data.Dataset.zip((images_ds, labels_ds)).batch(1)
```

I also tried to create the **labels_ds** like this:

```py
labels_ds.map(lambda x: tf.expand_dims(tf.one_hot(x, NUM_CATEGORIES), axis=0))
```

`categ_img`is a `pandas.DataFrame` containing image paths and labels under **image_name** and **category_label** columns respectively.

And I keep getting this error:
`InvalidArgumentError: logits and labels must have the same first dimension, got logits shape [1,50] and labels shape [50]`

My model is based on a pretrained **ResNet** model provided by Keras:

```py
base_model = ResNet50(weights='imagenet', include_top=False, input_shape=(None, None, 3))
for layer in base_model.layers:
    layer.trainable = False
x = base_model.output
x = GlobalAveragePooling2D()(x)

for fc in FC_LAYERS:
    x = Dense(fc, activation='relu')(x)
    x = Dropout(DROPOUT)(x)

output    = Dense(NUM_CATEGORIES, activation='softmax', name='fully-connected')(x)
model     = Model(inputs=base_model.input, outputs=output)
optimizer = tf.keras.optimizers.SGD(lr=LEARNING_RATE)
cce       = tf.keras.losses.CategoricalCrossentropy()

model.compile(optimizer, loss=cce)
return model
```

It is trained like this:

```py
model_classification.fit(
    ds,
    epochs=epochs,
    steps_per_epoch=steps
)
```

Which seems pretty straight-forward to me.

Any help would be appreciated.

Thank you.

Comment: what if you try **yield [one_hot]**  in your read_labels function?

Comment: @alift yes, it is like it does not matter if I return a matrix or a 1D np array. I still get the same error. I also tried to expand dims with numpy. Thank you for your help

Answer (score 0):

I finally tried something that worked.

Here is the line you need to change:

```py
model.compile(loss='categorical_crossentropy', optimizer='adam', metrics=['accuracy'])
```

I don't know why, but this made things working.